# Concise way to initialise a collection

Tags: c#, collections

I can initialise a class in a concise manner using something like:

```
public static readonly type TYPE_NAME = new type()
        {
            ClientIp = "ClientIp",
            LanguageCode = "LanguageCode",
            SessionToken = "SessionToken",
            SystemKey = "SystemKey"
        };
```

However is it possible to initialise a collection in a similar way (inherited from `List<>`)?

Comment: Sure, see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>{ "foo", "bar" };

List<Person> people = new List<Person>{
                                new Person { Name = "Pete", Age = 12},
                                new Person { Name = "Jim", Age = 15}
                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection initializer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
var l = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use collection initializer.
To use this,

```
List<int> collection=  List<int>{1,2,3,...};
```

To use collection initializer it need not to be exactly of List type.
Collection initializer can be used on those types that implements IEnumerable and has one public `Add` method.

You use Collection initializer feature even in the following type.

```
public class SomeUnUsefulClass:IEnumerable
    {
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public void Add(int i)
        {
            //It does not do anything.
        }
    }
```

Like,

```
 SomeUnUsefulClass cls=new SomeUnUsefulClass(){1,2,3,4,5};
```

which is perfectly valid.